# Solr with Jetty on LAMP server - Admin page access issue

Tags: linux, apache, solr, apache2, jetty

I have **Solr with its default Jetty** that came with example directory **installed on Linux** server which has **apache2 as its web server**.

Now, within the same private LAN, when I open a browser and type in `http://<ip-address>:8983/solr` works **ONLY** when I do port forwarding **otherwise it doesn't work**. I am not sure what could be the problem? Please note this installation has been done on a remote server in a hosting environment for production deployment and I am a beginner wrt deployment stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `jetty.host` parameter during startup to allow direct access to Jetty.

The -D option of the java command can be used with the followin syntax:

```
java -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0 -jar start.jar
```

In this way Jetty can be reached from all the hosts.

However this is not the ideal setup IMHO. I prefere to setup Jetty to listen only on localhost, implementing the client with another frontend server which listen on port 80. If you want to implement the frontend on another server you can use iptables to limit the incoming connection, dropping everything on the 8983 port if the IP is different from the one of your frontend server.

This image depicts my preferred setup for a LAMP stack includin SOLR:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much elbuild! I have a php app for frontend served by Apache2 on the same Linux server which uses solr url (solr, php, apache2, jetty, all are in just one single server). So, in that scenario, what can be done?

Comment: Apache listening on port 80 on all the IP, Jetty listening on all the IP on port 8983. iptables rule to exclude (drop) all the TCP connection on 8983 BUT the ones coming from your box IP. In this way you can still access Solr admin (Solritas) but your setup is secure and production ready.

Comment: Great! I am understanding a lot more now. For iptables to exclude all the TCP coonections on 8983 except the local IP, I would need to add a rule in iptables "/etc/sysconfig/iptables"??

Comment: Yes. Remember to save or restart iptables in order to apply the rules

Comment: Just as a trial, I have tried "java -Djetty.host=0.0.0.0 -jar start.jar", I am still not able to access http://<ip-address>:8983/solr :(

Comment: my issue is more or less same is this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958329/how-do-you-configure-jetty-to-allow-access-from-an-external-server

Comment: I looked at that issue, they suggest to edit the xml configuration. I personally never had to, but I think you can try and report if it works. If you edit your question with all the test you have done (and relevant log as well) you may have more answers.

Comment: I can certainly add log. Since it is on a different server, I would have to FTP upload the log. Btw, I was reading more about what you have explained in the diagram and what you did is reverse proxy is it?

Comment: I could achieve what I need using reverse proxy. Thanks for the direction!